# Cant access global variable in Vue 3 and Vite

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I have this App.js

```
import './bootstrap';
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';


const app = createApp({});

app.config.globalProperties.$globalVar = 'globa11lVar'

import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent.vue';
import ExampleComponent2 from './components/ExampleComponent2.vue';

const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: ExampleComponent },
    { path: '/about', component: ExampleComponent2 },
]

const router = createRouter({
.....
});

app.use(router);

app.mount('#app');
```

as you can see I have  `app.config.globalProperties.$globalVar` to pass the variable.

On my `ExampleComponent`

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted, watch } from 'vue'

// lifecycle hooks
onMounted(() => {
   console.log( app.config.globalProperties ); 
})

</script>
```

Im getting this error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: can't access property "globalProperties", app.config is undefined

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve that by using `getCurrentInstance`, but it's not a recommended way, you could use `inject/provide` to do the same thing :

```js
app.provide('globalVar', 'some globalVar')
```

in your component :

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted, watch, inject } from 'vue'

const globalVar = inject('globalVar')

// lifecycle hooks
onMounted(() => {
   console.log( globalVar ); 
})

</script>
```